# as3 textfield wordwrap true causing textwidth to be weird

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to wordwrap a textfield inside a button, however after i set wordwrap to true some unexpected behavior happened.

```
Button.width = 390;
Button.textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
Button.textField.border = true;
Button.textField.wordwrap = true;
Button.textField.multiline = true;
Button.textField.width = textButton.width - 10;
Button.textField.x = 5;
Button.height = 60;
```

This is what happens:

[image]

When I'm outputting the Button.textField.textWidth, it seems shown a value that so much less than Button or Button.textField.width. I just want to make the word break after textwidth meets the textField.width maximum value. Is there anything that I can do to change this behavior? …since I can't change the value of Button.textField.textWidth (read-only).

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the Button.textField.autoSize setting. This is probably what is throwing everything off.

You're setting the text field's width to match the size of the button when you set `width = textButton.width - 10`, but you're also telling it to automatically resize the textField to match the size of the actual text when you set the autoSize setting. So it's not going to fit the button the way you want it to.

Comment: After trying out to comment Button.textField.autoSize it became more weird XD, the second line of the word become invisible and can only be seen when im roll over the button. The Button.textField.textWidth is not changing either. I do have hunch this behavior is because i'm using fl.controls.button components. But i can't see what is wrong.

Comment: Try setting the width as well as the height to match that of the button. Have you got a screenshot of what happened?

Comment: The imgur link above is the screenshot. The width of textfield component is the same with the button, but somehow the text dont recognize that width and become considerably smaller.